# Can we make cold without producing heat?

Tags: cold-atoms

It seems to me you can put a heater on without expelling cold to the other room like an air conditioner and freezer would. Is there a way to reduce heat locally by slowing down molecules for example?
Even if it cannot be done at a big scale, could laser trapping be used to achieve the freezing of an entire object?

Edit: I am more interested in microscopic explanation of heat and cold than macroscopic concepts. If you cannot tell me what is heat in a molecule and why it cannot be cancelled by an opposing force, do not answer.

Comment: A big block of ice reduces heat in its surroundings by slowing down molecules.

Comment: @Gandalf: yes but in exchange it gets warmer.

Comment: Laser cooling works the same way. A population of atoms is cooled by moving heat elsewhere because the emitted photons have a shorter wavelength than the absorbed photons.

Comment: @Gandalf: I see. Is there a way to get an inelastic collision, and slow down a particle by introducing the same kinetic energy but in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what an **endothermic reaction** does, which is a type chemical or physical reaction that typically absorbs heat from its surroundings. A common endothermic reaction is observed in instant ice packs, where some chemicals are mixed that perform an endothermic reaction, absorbing heat from the environment and feeling cool to the touch. The ice pack "makes cold" by absorbing heat from its surroundings and storing it as increased *enthalpy* in the reactants. This is contrast to an air conditioner or refrierator, which uses a heat pump to move heat energy from one location to another - in the case of the endothermic reaction, the heat energy is actually absorbed and not just relocated.

Note that endothermic reactions happen in one direction and are then "spent". Once an ice cube melts and absorbs thermal energy, that's all it has to offer. If you want to be able to dump more heat into it, you'd need to re-freeze the water, which is now an exothermic reaction that will return heat energy to its surroundings.

Comment: Now we're talking. So I guess heat is stored as another form of energy in the pack?

Comment: @Exocytosis Yes, an endothermic reaction is defined by an increase in *enthalpy*, which is a measure of the total energy stored in a system. Another example is a melting ice cube, which remains at 0 degrees C until completely melted - it absorbs heat energy from its surroundings, but does not increase in temperature. This energy goes into breaking the physical bonds of the ice crystals.

Comment: But the ice cube will shrink (by melting) so what do you mean by saying it stays at 0°C?

Comment: @Exocytosis If you have a glass of ice water, it will be at 0C (the ice can't be warmer than that, and the water can't be colder than that). As the ice melts, the glass of water remains at 0C until all the ice is melted. Only then does the glass of water increase in temperature. The water molecules in the ice lattice at 0C turn into liquid water molecules at 0C, so the phase change is what's absorbing the heat energy - but whether it's solid ice or liquid water, it's still the same bit of matter that stays at 0C.

Comment: It should be noted that creating the reagents for the endothermic reaction generates heat, of at least that absorbed when running the reaction in the forward.  So whether you use an endothermic reaction or a cyclic operation like a refrigerator, it’s largely about convenience of when and where you generate the waste heat.

Answer (score -1):

#### No

You cannot “make cold” the same way you “make heat”.  The universe seems to follow the 2nd law of thermodynamics, which doesn’t allow you to “make cold” without an equal or greater amount of “making heat”.

There’s no such restriction on “make heat”; you can make as much as you want. If that seems unbalanced, note that “cold” is not “negative heat”. “Cold” is better described as “less heat”. So when you “make cold”, you are just moving “heat” from one object to another.

Comment: But ultimately, heat is motion (I am not talking about radiation). I understand it is difficult to track each molecule and alter their individual motion but why focused energy could not be used in a precise way to exactly counterbalance existing motion, I.e. heat of particles thus producing immobility and cold?

Comment: @Exocytosis what you're describing is a Maxwell's demon and is ruled out by Landauer's principle.